# Error when fetching acs data

Tags: r, acs

Can anyone help with this error?  I am trying to download population data.  I am not sure what this error is about.  Here is my code.

```
state.IN=geo.make(state="IN")
indiana.total.pop=acs.fetch(geography=state.IN,table.number="B01003")
```

> Error in `seq.default(1, (length(in.data) - geo.length), 2)` : 
>     wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: Apparently `(length(in.data) - geo.length)` leads to a `to` argument lower than the `from = 1` argument.  In that case, the `by` argument must be negative, since you're trying to create a descending sequence. Either you should just change `2` to `-2` (if you really want a descending sequence), or you got confused with your `to` argument calculation.

Comment: My API key was incorrect.  Fixing that resolved my issue.  Thanks

Comment: Having similar issue here `acs.lookup(table.number = "S2503")` that produces:
`Error in seq.default(1, length(names), 2) : wrong sign in 'by' argument` @Molx Seems to be issue with tables beginning with S

Comment: Had the same problem. The solution was simple for me: make sure you activate your API key via the link sent to your email address.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run `acs::api.key.install("YOUR CENSUS KEY")` before working with any of the acs functions.  I was getting the same error, and once I fixed my api key install, it resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

i changed the endyear from 2011 to 2014 and it fixed it for me